# Store MySQL table to file (sqlite?)

Tags: c++, mysql, sqlite, qt, mysql++

I wrote a C++/QT application that uses a mysql database for its data. It's using the mysql++ library. I now want it to be able to export and import its data to/from files.

I could write an own file format, but I'd like to elude this efford, if possible.

Is there an easy possibility to export a mysql table into a file and to reimport this file with C++?

I heard of sqlite, but as far as I read, migrating from mysql++ to sqlite is not that easy, because it includes a switch of the complete database backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "LOAD DATA " and "SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE"

That should have great performance. You may not use the outfiles further as easily as you want.

Comment: Ah didn't knew them. Looks good. Is this also working, when the mysql server is remote?

Comment: Sure, MySQL as database is designed to operate in server/client mode. Only some administrative actions can't be performed on client side.

Comment: You're right but in standard mode mysql wants the files on the server. I have them on the client. There is "LOAD DATA LOCAL" for loading a local file from the client. But I didn't find a possibility to say "SELECT INTO LOCAL OUTFILE". Is there any?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to export/import data from/to a database is `xml` files.

Comment: Is there a mysql<->xml library or another easy way to do it? I don't want to create an own file format that must be changed every time I change my mysql database structure.